# How can i flush content to client without waiting to end request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC action method as below i directly write to response and flush it in every second but i can see results at the end of the request.

Is there a solution to flush written content to client without waiting end of request ?

```
    public void SampleTask()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Response.Write(i + " is working /n/n");
            Response.Flush();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it is just client side content, can't you do on client side itself. something like this $('div').html('');

Comment: may be you need to implement it by ajax requests from client side..

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to a Generic Handler... MVC wants you to return a result (ActionResult, JsonResult, etc) so that the response is buffered. In a generic handler, you have more finer grain control of the response and it's output.